# How to select top N elements from a JavaPairRDD ? -Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, truncate

I have obtained a key/value pair, and sorted it into a new JavaPairRDD

Now, I need to select the top 5 elements from it, that is, to obtain a new JavaPairRDD with those top 5 elements in it.

How would I do that ?

Is there a simpler way than using the flatMap, since it seems like the unnecessary extra work ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `rdd.take(5)`?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it was inherited in API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about order, you can use `RDD.take(5)` to get the first 5 elements in an RDD.

Comment: True, since it was sorted, however, I was expecting not to convert it back to another RDD.  That would speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

To get the top (or bottom) items (and answer the question you asked), you could use:

```
.takeOrdered(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T]
```

Comment: Thank you, a JAVA syntax would be:   takeOrdered(int num, scala.math.Ordering<T> ord)

Comment: But will it re-sort? :)

Answer (score 0):

*Syntax for using getting the **smallest** value of a priority queue:*

```
assuming resultRdd = RDD[Double]
resultRdd.map (y => y.takeOrdered(x)(Ordering.by[Double]())
```

*Syntax for using getting the **largest** value of a priority queue:*

```
assuming resultRdd = RDD[Double]
resultRdd.map (y => y.top(x)(Ordering.by[Double]())
```

**Note**: 
( top reverses the order and internally invokes takeOrdered )

```
def top(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T] = takeOrdered(num)(ord.reverse)
```