# last element in RDD using python spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to get the last element information from a Spark RDD. 
I have sorted the RDD with respective the value of a `(key, value)` pair.

My data in RDD

```
(8, 0.98772733936789858)

(4, 3.0599761935471004)

(2, 3.1913934060593321)

(1, 4.9646263295153013)

(5, 5.3596802463208792)

(7, 5.5829277439661071)

(9, 6.4739040233992258)

(0, 6.9343681509951081)

(6, 7.4699692671955953)

(3, 8.6579764626088771)
```

I am able to get the first `(key, value)` pair using the first function, but not able to figure out how to get the last one. I can do a swap of `(key, value)` pair to `(value, key)` pair and get the required data using .max function. However, is there any other way to get the last element from a RDD using Python spark?

Comment: Dup of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862725/how-to-select-top-n-elements-from-a-javapairrdd-apache-spark/28866931#28866931

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are other ways.

Here are a few (including yours) along with a very informal ranking of performance based on 1000 tests per method with one local worker thread on my machine -- using the dataset you provided in the question.

### 1) max()

> Find the maximum item in this RDD.

```
output = (
          rdd.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
          .max()
         )
```

This was the 1st fastest on average.

### 2) sortByKey() -- with first()

> Sorts this RDD, which is assumed to consist of (key, value) pairs.
>
> Return the first element in this RDD.

```
output = (
          rdd.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
          .sortByKey(ascending=False)
          .first()
         )
```

This was the 4th fastest on average.

### 3) top()

> Get the top N elements from a RDD.

```
output = (
          rdd.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))
          .top(1)
         )
```

This was the 3rd fastest on average

### 4) top() -- with comparison key

> Get the top N elements from a RDD.

```
output = (
          rdd.top(1, key=lambda x: x[1])
         )
```

This was the 2nd fastest on average.

### Final thoughts

You'll notice that the 4th method doesn't swap the (key/value)'s.  Instead it sweeps over the rdd with *key* ('key' the argument -- not part of your rdd) specifying a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable, and in this case the comparison key is the second item in the your (key, value) tuples, i.e. value.

So **method 1, max(), is perfectly good.**  But...

**Once you're in the territory where you need the 'last *n* elements'** (i.e. more than just the last element) **then I would say method 4 is the preferred way to go.**

Answer (score 3):

RDD.first() is pretty efficient because it can be executed in a short-circuit fashion. Since you're sorting the data anyway, by the second value in the tuple, sort the RDD reversed and then just take the first element.