# how to get the last value from a RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get the last value of `RDD`,
this my code:

```
 val rdd=sc.parallelize(0 to 10,1)
 val last=rdd.sortBy(x=>{x},false,1).first()
 println(last)
```

It's so inefficient,anyone has better way?Thanks!

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363923/2308683?

Comment: It solved my question，thanks！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max` function if you are looking to get a last value after sorting

```
rdd.max()
```

Or you can use `top` function

```
rdd.top(1)
```

Comment: Won't this only work for comparable objects? It's not a general solution to get the end of an RDD